# Как в Atom сделать сочетание клавиш которое будет писать текст?

Tags: html, atom

Я хочу чтобы, например, при одновременном нажатии на ctrl+shift+p в Atom'е, у меня в поле для текста печаталось `<p></p>` и всё в таком духе. Я попытался поискать в инете, но то чего мне нужно было не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

В файле keymap.cson (File->Keymap...) пишем

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-b': 'custom:doComment'
```

В файле init.coffee (File-> Init Script...) пишем

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'custom:doComment', ->
  atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('<p></p>')
```

Рестартните программу. Теперь при нажатии Ctrl+B в редакторе текста должно напечатать `<p></p>`.

PS

Если хотите чтобы курсор был между тэгами `<p></p>`, то в файле init.coffee пишем

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'custom:doComment', ->
  atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('<p></p>')
  atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.moveLeft(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Существует для многих редакторов (в том числе и для Atom) плагин `Emmet` позволяющий ускорить web-разработку в несколько раз (в вашем случае написании тегов)

Comment: Я посмотрел, там вроде сразу много всего он пишет и немного не то что мне нужно. Мне именно нужно чтобы он писал то что мне нужно (и это можно ещё и самому задавать (например даже то что не связанно с html, или css, и тп, на пример после сочетания клавиш пишет: "`<a href="/Personel/" class="links1"> <br></a>`")) после сочетания клавиш.

Comment: @Unr_Uzb, это называется снипеты (в Атоме они тоже должны быть). Но на самом деле это можно быстро делать с emmet

Answer (score 0):

В Atom есть встроенные сниппеты, которые вы можете задавать сами, с нужными вам характеристиками. Об можно прочитать, к примеру, [здесь](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)